# How to format comments with one space between // and words?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, comments

How to automatically format comments with one space between // and words? For example, selecting format in my editors should convert

> `//login` to `// login`

```
public interface LoginService {
    //login // -> // login
    SysAdminDO login(LoginForm form);
}
```

Comment: Just put a space, what else are you looking there for?

Comment: @nullpointer Not put a space manually, I want to format by `CTRL + ALT + L`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the setting

***Editor ~> Code Style ~> Java(language) ~> Code Generation***

[image]

Or else you can alternatively use ***Comment with line comment*** shortcut

[image]

Just type a line and on that line use the shortcut. e.g.

```
String var;
I would make this a comment [Press the shortcut]
// I would make this a comment
```

Comment: @JohnChou Updated wit line comment as well.

Comment: @Yes, this works for a new comment line, but how to format comments that already in projects ?

Comment: @JohnChou For existing code, not very sure of that for line comments. Formatting classes helps formatting /** comments but not // to what I can see. You can try [reformatting the code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformatting-source-code.html#refromat).